# Run Processes as TrustedInstaller in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a way/API to run processes under the service `TrustedInstaller` in .NET?

I don't want to use a command-line tool like [devxexec](http://developex.com/custom-software/devxexec.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the DevXExec page a little further - they approximate their strategy.

1. Grab token of existing process - `OpenProcessToken`.
2. Copy it - `DuplicateTokenEx`.
3. Modify session id of the copy - `SetTokenInformation`.
4. Create a new process using copied token - `CreateProcessAsUser`.

All of these Win32 APIs are PInvoke'able - bunch of reading to do on MSDN tho'.

Comment: Can you explain the process? I have no idea on how to use those APIs.

Comment: I'm not going to write your code - but when I said PInvoke'able - the path is fairly straightforward.  Stitching together PInvokess of these Win32 APIs e.g. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/OpenProcessToken.html  If you're not up for Win32 interop work - DevXExec seems like an easier path.

Answer (score 0):

I think any Setup and Deployment Project/ Processes would be considered as TrustedInstaller.